# Prove $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{x - 1 - \ln \left( x \right)}}{{-x +1 + x\ln \left( x \right)}} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Using the standard definition of a limit,
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \alpha } f(x) = l \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon  > 0 ;\exists \sigma  > 0:\left| {x - \alpha } \right| < \sigma  \Rightarrow \left| {f(x) - l} \right| < \varepsilon$$

> Prove that 
>   $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{{x - 1 - \ln \left( x \right)}}{{-x + 1 + x\ln \left( x \right)}}=1$$

---

My try:

$
\begin{array}{l}
 \ln \left( {x + 1} \right) = x - \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + o\left( {x^3 } \right)\quad ;\quad \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} o\left( {x^3 } \right) = 0 \\ 
  \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x - \ln \left( {x + 1} \right) = \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + o\left( {x^3 } \right) \\ 
 \left( {x + 1} \right)\ln \left( {x + 1} \right) = x + \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + o\left( {x^3 } \right) \\ 
  - x + \left( {x + 1} \right)\ln \left( {x + 1} \right) =  + \frac{{x^2 }}{2} + o\left( {x^3 } \right) \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{x - \ln \left( {x + 1} \right)}}{{ - x + \left( {x + 1} \right)\ln \left( {x + 1} \right)}} = \frac{{\frac{{x^2 }}{2}}}{{\frac{{x^2 }}{2}}} = 1 \\ 
  \Leftrightarrow \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{x - 1 - \ln \left( x \right)}}{{1 - x + x\ln \left( x \right)}} = 1 \\ 
 \end{array}
$

Comment: You don't need to write `\mathop\lim\limits`. Just `\lim_{x\to a}` looks like $\lim_{x\to a} $.

Answer (score 2):

No, this proof isn't correct. The definition of the limit includes the implication: $|x-\alpha|<\sigma \implies |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$. But you have proved the converse $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon \implies |x-\alpha|<\sigma$ (with $l=\alpha=1$ in this case), and the converse of an implication is not equivalent to the implication.

Now, your proof might be able to be easily turned into a proof of the correct implication (if all your steps were reversible, for example). But as it stands, it's not proving the right thing.

Comment: Please how can I correct the error

Comment: A correct proof would look like this: "Define $\sigma=e^\epsilon-1$. If $|x-1|<\sigma$, then ... [a bunch of smart stuff] ... and so $|f(x)-1| < \epsilon$." It might be that you can use your original steps, in reverse, to fill in the [smart stuff]. Or you might need to make some modifications, or even to change the definition of $\sigma$ - whatever makes the proof work in the end is fine.

Comment: Gentlemen are requested to comment on the answer

Comment: Ladies too...? :/

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x-1-\ln x}{1-x+x\ln x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\left ( x-1-\ln x \right )}{\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}\left ( 1-x+x\ln x \right )}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x-1}{x\ln x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{x}\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}x=1$$